# Method from superclass "does not exist" in type....?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, typescript-typings

we have a TS app that uses a JS library to which we built a .d.ts file to use it with TypeScript.
When we had that file in a "typings" folder inside the project, everything was working fine. However, we decided to move those typings to a separate repo in order to share it with other projects.

Issue: After moving the typings to an external repo, the IDE (both Idea and VSCode) no longer recognize the properties and methods from the super type. The app compiles, runs and all features work. But the IDEs keep saying the files have errors.

Any ideas?

Typing repo structure is like this:

```
-custom-typings
  - index.d.ts
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "custom-typings",
  "author": "Author Name",
  "version": "0.1.3",
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "next"
  }
}
```

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2015",
      "ES2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "pretty": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "ES2020"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
  ],
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true
  }
}
```

index.d.ts

```
declare module 'custom-typings' {

  export class A {
    aMethod();
  }

  export class B extends A{
    bProperty: any = {foo: 'Foo'};
  }

  const CustomTypes: {
    B: typeof B;
  };

  export default CustomTypes
}
```

Using the types:

```
import CustomTypes from 'custom-typings';

class MyComponent extends CustomTypes.B {
  
  init() {
    console.log(this.bProperty.foo); // property 'bProperty' does not exist in type MyComponent
    this.aMethod(); // property 'aMethod' does not exist in type MyComponent
  }
}
```

Comment: `B` doesn't appear to be in scope, are you not getting an error from that?

Comment: Hi @Bergi. Just edited it. It is actually CustomTypes.B. The only error I get is the one mentioned. We can navigate to the types by CTRL + Clicking them. The syntaxe is highlighted but there is always this message.

Comment: The default export of the module is an object which is declared to have a `C` property only - this should not work. Try `import * as CustomTypes from '…'` or `import { B } from '…';` instead

Comment: I'm sorry again.. just updated it. It is actually CustomTypes.C. I can't post the actual code here, so I missed that in the "translation"

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit. I think the problem is that `C` is actually a different type than `B`. Typescript might know that the constructor has the same type as the `B` constructor, but they're still distinct.

Comment: Even if I change to, for example, import {B} from 'custom-typings'; and extends B. The behavior is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it happened that the structure of the "custom-typings" repo was preventing the project to resolve the types.

We were writing types definitions for an existing library that had its own module declared. Our repo was declaring the module with the same name as the lib's one, let's call it "lib-module".

The types repo needs to contain a directory called "lib-module" and declare the module with that same name:

```
declare module "lib-module" {
    // properties and functions here
}
```

and the new structure is:

```
-custom-typings
  - lib-module
    - index.d.ts
  - tsconfig.json
  - package.json
```

This way, any project can import the types like:

```
import CustomTypes from 'lib-module';
```